# Why won't python append to this file?

Tags: python, file, file-io

So, I'm working on this project where I have a 34mb text file full of song data. Each line has a year,artist,unique number and song separated by the string `<SEP>`. Now, I have sorted each of those things into different lists. What I want to do now is sort the artists into a different text file. The problem is python will create the file but will not print to it, the file size is 0 bytes. Here's my code:

```
#Opening the file to read here
with open('tracks_per_year.txt', 'r',encoding='utf8') as in_file:
    #Creating 'lists' to put information from array into
    years=[]
    uics=[]
    artists=[]
    songs=[]

    #Filling up the 'lists'
    for line in in_file:
        year,uic,artist,song=line.split("<SEP>")
        years.append(year)
        uics.append(uic)
        artists.append(artist)
        songs.append(song)
        print(year)
        print(uic)
        print(artist)
        print(song)



#Sorting:
with open('artistssorted.txt', 'a') as artist:

    for x in range(1000000):
        x=1
        if artists[x-1]==artists[x]:
            artist.write (years[x])
            artist.write(" ")
            artist.write(uics[x])
            artist.write(" ")
            artist.write(artists[x])
            artist.write(" ")
            artist.write(songs[x])
            artist.write("\n")
        else:
            x=x+1
```

Just FYI, uics= unique identifier codes
Also, if you guys have any other recommendations on how to sort this file i'd be glad to hear it. Just keep in mind I am a novice.

Comment: Your `for` loop looks a little strange. Why do `x=1` and `x = x+1`? x should increment automatically without those. If you want the loop to start at 1, do `for x in range(1, 10000000):`

Comment: You know the second for-loop is infinite?

Comment: @EarlGrey it's not infinite, but it's always going to write the first value. The `range` will eventually raise `StopIteration`

Comment: You should store info in a list of tuples (artist, year, uic, song) and then sort it.

Comment: @WayneWerner No writing occurs if 2 first entries are not equal.

Comment: @Wayne Werner I see...Forgot about how Python handles such loops

Comment: @EricFortin, right. I should've said it's always going to operate on the 1st item(s) in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition `if artists[x-1]==artists[x]:` will always be false if the first 2 artists entry are not equals since you override x with 1 for every loop iteration. Writing in the file will then never happen.

When using range iteration, the variable gets incremented automatically so no need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my hit:

```
#Opening the file to read here
with open('tracks_per_year.txt', 'r',encoding='utf8') as in_file:
    #Creating 'lists' to put information from array into
    records = []

    #Filling up the 'lists'
    for line in in_file:
        year, uic, artist, song=line.split("<SEP>")
        records.append((artist, year, uic, song))

#Sorting:
records.sort()
with open('artistssorted.txt', 'a') as artist_file:

    for (artist, year,uic,song) in records:
        artist_file.write("%s %s %s %s\n"%(year, uic, artist, song))
```